# Python type hint class as either object or list

Tags: python, type-hinting

I would like to have a `list` of objects with the feature that `my_list.`{attribute name} should return the values of any attribute name. For example `m_list.weight` -> `[23, 45, 78]`.

One way to do this is to create a DB subclass of list. My problem is with type hinting. For example:

```
T = TypeVar('T')


class DB(list[T], T):  # The extra T is to autocomplete T's attributes.
    """A database."""

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name) -> 'DB':
        """Return a list of attribute values.

        Usage:
            db = DB(item1, item2, ...)
            print(db.weights)   # A list of the items' weights.
        """
        result = DB(getattr(x, attr_name) for x in self)
        return result


@dataclass
class Item:
    name: str
    weight: float


inventory : DB[Item] = DB([Item('Steak', 3), Item('Sauce', 0.2)])
print(inventory[0].weight)  # <---- This works to autocomplete name/weight of a single item.
print(inventory.            # <---- How to autocomplete name/weight here?
```

Interestingly, this code autocompletes in PyCharm. However it throws an error when executing:

```
    class DB(list[T], T):  # The extra T is to autocomplete T's attributes.
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

One way to get around the issue is to remove the reference to T in DB and create a subclass of DB like this:

```
class DB(list[T]):  # Removed the second T.

...

class Inventory(DB[Item]):
    name: DB[str]
    weight: DB[float]
```

The first way is simpler--if it would work. Is there a solution for this yet?

Comment: Inheriting from a type variable doesn't make sense, you want to use `Generic[T]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Do you mean class `DB(list[T], Generic[T]):`? That doesn't autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly type hinting `inventory` does the trick. It autocompletes and does not throw any runtime errors.

```
T = TypeVar('T')


class DB(list[T]):  # The extra T is to autocomplete T's attributes.
    """A database."""

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name) -> 'DB':
        """Return a list of attribute values.

        Usage:
            db = DB(item1, item2, ...)
            print(db.weights)   # A list of the items' weights.
        """
        result = DB(getattr(x, attr_name) for x in self)
        return result


@dataclass
class Item:
    name: str
    weight: float


inventory : Union[DB[Item], Item] = DB([Item('Steak', 3), Item('Sauce', 0.2)])
print(inventory[0].weight)  # <---- This works to autocomplete name/weight of a single item.
print(inventory.weight      # <---- This now works too!
```

It seems to work fine, even though it may not be what the language architects had in mind.

Comment: Not any more with mypy 0.931: 
```
% mypy test/test1.py 
test/test1.py:29: error: Value of type "Union[DB[Item], Item]" is not indexable
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```